# Closure stylesheets parse error with Twitter's bootstrap.css

Tags: google-closure-compiler, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using closure-stylesheets-20111202.jar to combine and minify all my CSS. However it's throwing an error on the Twitter's bootstrap.css on something that looks fine to me.

```
Compiler parsing error: Parse error in bootstrap.css at line 1404 column 95:
background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333333), to(#222222));
```

Any thoughts? I know I can just concatenate their already minified version to mine but was wondering if anyone had a proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is a bug in Closure Stylesheets. I am working on a fix.

Basically, `GssParserCC.jj` needs to change on line 59:

```
private static final Pattern FUNCTIONS_WITH_SPACE_SEP_OK = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:-(?:O|MOZ|WEBKIT|MS)-)?(?:REPEATING-)?(?:LINEAR|RADIAL)-GRADIENT"
    + "|RECT|-WEBKIT-GRADIENT|-KHTML-GRADIENT",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

and `CssFunctionNode.java` needs to have `-khtml-gradient` added to its list.

However, that will not fix everything because Closure Stylesheets does not recognize the following yet:

```
border-radius: 0 \0;
```

In particular, it's the slash that is throwing it off.

Though even if I replace that line with:

```
border-radius: 0;
```

Then I get 96 errors of various sorts.

`--allow-unrecognized-functions` gets that number down to 85.

The remaining 85 look to be of the form:

```
Detected multiple identical, non-alternate declarations in the same ruleset. If this is intentional please use the /* @alternate */ annotation. background-image:[-o-linear-gradient(top,#5bc0de,#339bb9)] in bootstrap.css at line 1872 column 1:
```

There is no flag to suppress this type of warning at the moment.

This conversation is probably best had on http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/issues/list

Comment: Partial fix checked in: http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/source/detail?r=e1b66f7c9a72da09fd9876e6e1d243620aaf1cea